# Subquery Group By Month and Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with three columns:

```
id (nvarchar)
time (datetime)
description (nvarchar)
```

and want to calculate the following quantity:

```
SELECT 
(
(SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT id) as float)
FROM [table]
WHERE description = 'x'
) / 
(
(SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT id) as float)
FROM [table])
)
AS quotient
```

Is there a way to calculate this same quotient for each month and year instead of for the entire table? I tried `GROUP BY MONTH(time) + YEAR(time)` at the end but got the error that:

> the multi-part identifier could not be bound.

Comment: Post the query that you're having trouble with, the *exact* error message, and preferably, some example input/output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(time), MONTH(time), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN description = 'x' THEN id END)  /
       (COUNT(DISTINCT id) * 1.0) AS quotient
FROM [table]
GROUP BY YEAR(time), MONTH(time)
```

Comment: This almost works but I think it double counts some ids that appear in multiple months since the aggregate total doesn't match what I get if I run my original query. Would it be possible to only count the first instance of each id? so keeping only the minimum time for each id.